# Manual entry of recurring donation

Tags: drupal, donations

We're moving over to CiviCRM. We don't currently use - or actually really plan to use - it for our donations, many of which are just sent as regular bank transfers. I'd like to be able to record these on CiviCRM without entering them manually, but can't see a way to do this - any thoughts?

Answer (score 3):

There is an [extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/offline-recurring-payment) available for adding offline recurring contributions but unfortunately the tag says it works till 4.4. Might be worth contacting [maintainer](https://www.circle-interactive.co.uk/contact) if they have any plans to upgrade.

Pradeep

Comment: Thanks Pradeep - was not aware of that extension, however, I think it's best to get the information directly from the payment processor in case of rejected/failed transactions and cancellations - in this way the user would not have to worry about maintaining things manually.

Comment: There are some organization which takes recurring donation in the form of Check or Cash. The offline recurring extension was meant to use for such use case. It has a schedule job that creates pending contribution based on recurring interval and instalments and then admin/staff adds payment through offline form once the they get payment.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not processing the contributions directly through CiviCRM, then there is no way to create what Civi refers to as a recurring donation. There are, however other options:

1. [Import contributions](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/contributions/manual-entry-of-contributions/#importing-contributions) received on a periodic (e.g. monthly) basis
2. Have a programmer develop an interface with whatever system you are using to process the donations to feed the information into CiviCRM

If you tell me the name of the system you are using for payment processing, I can let you know if an extension exists for it.